# back button in android

Tags: android

Hello
In my android application i have a video list screen,a buffering screen and a videoplayer screen.
As soon as the user clicks an item from videolist screen ,he is navigated to buffering screen and then to videoplayer.
In the buffering screen i am using Async task and doing the loading process in on background process.

Now my issue is like the user if has selested a video then gets navigated to buffering screen.But if the user clicks back when he is in buffering screen then initially he is getting navigated to videolist screen but immediately after that again he is navigated to videoplayer screen.

What i would like to have is either the back button should be made disable in buffering or should prevent the player tostart if back is clicked.

Could you please let me know your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Of course, this is something that wouldn't happen if you code correctly. So, the problem is your code, thus if you don't provide the code it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: The code that i have is too long.So have not pasted to avoid confusion.

Comment: As of now i am not using any application states.Will my problem get solved if i use any application states here.

Comment: Create a shorter summary. Without seeing how you are calling your AsyncTask, and what the task does when it is finished, we can't really help.

Comment: Please reconsider blocking the back button (I see you've marked this answer as correct). I'd suggest reading this blog post and reading through some of the linked samples: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html. Blocking the back button prevents users from canceling buffering. Imagine if the buffering got stuck. Your user would be stuck looking at the buffering screen, unable to go back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to simply intercept the back button pressed the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) has a simple example

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do something on back.
return;
}
```

You could have it just do nothing at all, if you wish ;)

Comment: Please don't do this... it's very annoying for people who wish to cancel the buffering of a video (maybe they clicked the wrong button?). I'd uninstall your app if it blocked the back button.

Comment: Yes I agree, I meant to add to my answer that this would be a very 'cheap' way out of the problem. You would be better off stepping through your code and figuring out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I used to do it in a way:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
       //do smth
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```